# Get vector of pointers from vector in C++

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Is there an easy way of creating a vector of pointers to the elements of a vector?

i.e. easier than the below

```
std::vector<T*> fn(std::vector<T> &v)
{
  std::vector<T*> r;

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
    r.push_back(&v[i]);
  }

  return r;
}
```

EDIT: Incoming vector by reference

Comment: What for? In any case, what you have now is bad: you're getting pointers to elements of the function-local variable `v`; those pointers dangle as soon as you return. You should make the parameter a reference.

Comment: The example given will result in a vector of pointers to objects that don't exist after the function exits. I assume you want the prototype to be `std::vector<T*> fn(std::vector<T>& v)` i.e. pass a reference of the source vector, not a copy, which will be destroyed.

Comment: That code creates dangling pointers and will easily crash or behave unexpectedly on most systems because `v` and all of its elements are deallocated once `fn` is left.

Comment: Sorry yes, missed an ampersand

Comment: Then I just re-iterate: [what for](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)?

Comment: Please describe why you need this, I'm pretty sure there is a better way. Even if you pass by reference, there is no guarantee that the original `vector<T>` remains in existence as long as the `vector<T*>` is used. This will easily create dangling pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Benoit suggested, it is a bad idea to store these pointers. But if you *really* want to do it, you can use `std::transform` like this:

```
template<class T>
struct Address
{
    T* operator()(T& t) const
    {
        return &t;
    }
};


template<class T>
vector<T*> fn(vector<T>&  v)
{
  vector<T*> r;
  transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(r), Address<T>());
  return r;
}


int main( void )
{
    vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(0);
    fn(a);
}
```

Comment: Acknowledging everyone who pointed out it was a daft thing to do, which it undoubtedly was, thanks for this answer which is useful knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

I see no reason why you would need to do this. If you grow `v` your pointers may become invalid; and `r[i]` are just aliases for `&v[i]`.

If you really need to pass pointers (we still did not understand why) you can just pass `&v[0]` and the size of the vector. Given that all implementation of `std::vector` must guarantee that elements in a vector are stored contiguously in memory, you can deduce all addresses from the address of the first element and the size of the vector.

Comment: True, but in my (silly) case the vector is resized once, and I need to subsequently pass around vector<T*>s

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard library function to do this.

```
std::vector<T*> pv(v.size());
for (size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
    pv[i] = &v[i];
```

is probably the shortest expression of this loop if you don't use C++0x lambdas.

Comment: @xtofl: Why not? You really think that has any cost?

Comment: @xtofl: I don't care much about micro-optimization in a program that performs such a perverse action. (But FYI: my compiler optimizes this away.)

Comment: @GMan: the complexity of `size` is required to be <= O(N).  For `vector`, it will be constant.  It may be personal, but I prefer using iterators.  It's a bit about advocating them, too, I guess.

Comment: @xtofl: I think, by the way, in C++0x it has to be O(1) for all containers.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
T* mk_ptr(T& t) {
  return &t;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T*> fn(std::vector<T>& v) {
  std::vector<T*> r;
  std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(r), mk_ptr);
  return r;
}
```

But one has to wonder about the motivation of this... There are iterators for a reason. Noone guarantees that the pointers will remain valid.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to find a *correct* way. Your code (*edit:* the original code where `v` is passed by value, that is) is wrong and gives rise to undefined behavior. Depending on the application, you usually want either a [pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) or a normal container that stores [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).